# KDB - handling multiple data types in a single column

Tags: kdb

I've got a data set that consists of a column of string values that I am importing as symbols. Unfortunately the value column is a either a date, integer or float depending on the data type identified in column value_type.

I've created the `value_type` field manually in order to "flag" what type of data `value` is so I have the ability to modify or add more as needed.

My goal is to convert all of these into integer months so I can generate time series data from iStart. `i.e (iEnd: iStart + 0+ til desired_months`) I've included `desired_months` as the column I'd like to generate based on the various data in column `value`

A conditional switch seems appropriate here but I hadn't been able to get it working. The date parsing seems to be the most problematic. I keep thinking something akin to `is number=1b` or `is date=1b` would be helpful.

Thanks in advance for any input.

```
show t;

Symbol  Symbol       Symbol        Symbol            Integer   
id      iStart        value    value_type       desired_months
---|--------------------------------- 
AAA|    2014.08   02/01/2015     date                      6           
BBB|    2014.08   1              month                     1           
CCC|    2014.08   2              year                     24 
DDD|    2014.08   3              months                    3 
EEE|    2014.08   4.5            years                    54 
FFF|    2014.08   2016.01.02     date                     17 
GGG|    2014.08   10/1/2014      date                      2 
HHH|    2014.08   24             months                   24 
III|    2014.08   07/2015        date_part                11 
JJJ|    2014.08   2/16           date_part                18
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to tackle this might be to create a dictionary of functions which transform `value` based on what its `val_type` is. See below

```
q)dict:`date`month`year`date_part!({abs y-"m"$"D"$x};{[x;y]"F"$x};{[x;y]12*"F"$x};{abs y-"M"$"/"sv$[5>count x;("20";"0"),';]reverse"/"vs x})
q)dict
date     | {abs y-"m"$"D"$x}
month    | {[x;y]"F"$x}
year     | {[x;y]12*"F"$x}
date_part| {abs y-"M"$"/"sv$[5>count x;("20";"0"),';]reverse"/"vs x}
```

Then we can use this dictionary in an update to the original table to return

```
q)update desired_months:`int${[x;y;z;s]get each(x y),'enlist'[z],'s}[dict;val_type;string val;iStart]from t
iStart  val        val_type  desired_months
-------------------------------------------
2014.08 02/01/2015 date      6
2014.08 1          month     1
2014.08 2          year      24
2014.08 3          month     3
2014.08 4.5        year      54
2014.08 2016.01.02 date      17
2014.08 10/1/2014  date      2
2014.08 24         month     24
2014.08 07/2015    date_part 11
2014.08 2/16       date_part 18
```

One difficulty with this is the inconsistencies with `value`. The format of `date` & `date_part` is not consistent which means more thorough functions may need to be developed to cover all possibilites.

Comment: Thank you again Cathal!  I'll soak on this overnight and implement this in the am.  I think I can "tag" the val_type in but it really is the annoying permutations of written text. It seems like data conditioning is the hardest portion. I'll post back in the morning when I get it working.

Comment: Tested this morning and thank you again. I think this will work great!  I'll be able to incorporate more functions into the dictionary as new permutations arise!